# JavaFX read video from bytes

Tags: java, http, javafx

I'm trying to let a JavaFX video player read a video from a byte array.
I've found out that only `HTTP` and `file` URIs are supported so the only way to do it is run a HTTP server that sends the media player the video from the byte array. So how can I send all the video over HTTP protocol using `Socket`?

Comment: Where are you trying to get the video from? Is it on the same computer as your  JavaFX program?

Comment: yes, I'm making the application connect to itself

Comment: Why not use a `file` URI then?

Comment: I forgot to say that the program reads an encrypted video and when I open the video I didn't want to write it decrypted in a file

Comment: But you still want the program to play the decrypted video?

Comment: What I was thinking was reading the encrypted file, decrypt it and then send the media player the video after decrypting